# parse error for Fixture in unit test framework

Tags: matlab, unit-testing, xunit

I'm trying the following tutorial found on the MathWorks website
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-basic-custom-fixture.html

However when I try to run the code, it comes up with the following error:

```
Error using FormatHexFixture
The specified superclass 'matlab.unittest.fixtures.Fixture'
contains a parse error or cannot be found on MATLAB's
search path, possibly shadowed by another file with the
same name.
```

The code is as follows:

```
classdef FormatHexFixture < matlab.unittest.fixtures.Fixture
   properties (Access = private)
        OriginalFormat;
   end

   methods
       function setup(fixture)
          fixture.OriginalFormat = get(0, 'Format');
          set(0, 'Format', 'hex')
       end

       function teardown(fixture)
          set(0, 'format', fixture.OriginalFormat); 
       end
   end

end
```

with the SampleTest code as:

```
classdef SampleTest < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods(Test)
        function test1(testCase)
           testCase.applyFixture(FormatHexFixture)
           actStr = getColumnForDisplay([1;2;3], 'Small Integers');
           expStr = ['Small Integers  '
                '3ff0000000000000'
                '4000000000000000'
                '4008000000000000'];
           testCase.verifyEqual(actStr, expStr);
        end
    end
end

function str = getColumnForDisplay(values, title)
    elements = cell(numel(values)+1, 1);
    elements{1} = title;
    for idx = 1:numel(values)
      elements{idx+1} = displayNumber(values(idx));
    end
    str = char(elements);
end

function str = displayNumber(n)
    str = strtrim(evalc('disp(n);'));
end
```

Even when this is run, errors occur. What could be going on here? I have set the folders to my current directory.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the functionality for custom unit test fixtures (and specifically the package `matlab.unittest.fixtures`) was introduced in version R2013b of MATLAB, and that if you're on an older version it won't be available.

Are you on an older version?

Comment: Agreed this is most likely what is going on, but simple correction - Fixtures were introduced in R2014a.

Comment: That'll be the issue, then.